# Mounting a gcePersistentDisk kubernetes volume is very slow

Tags: docker, containers, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes

I start a kubernetes replication controller. When the corresponding container in the single pod in this replication controller has a `gcePersistentDisk` specified the pods will start very slow. After 5 minutes the pod is still in the `Pending` state.

`kubectl get po` will tell me:

```
NAME          READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
app-1-a4ni7   0/1       Pending   0          5m
```

Without the `gcePersistentDisk` the pod is `Running` in max 30 seconds.

(I am using a 10 GB Google Cloud Storage disk and I know that these disks have [lower performance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23683271/454103) for lower capacities, but I am not sure this is the issue.)

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Are your disks created in the same Zone as the cluster?

Comment: Yes, because not being in the same zone it will not work at all. That is specified.

Answer (score 5):

We've seen the GCE PD attach calls take upwards of 10 minutes to complete, so this is more or less expected. For example see https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/15382#issuecomment-153268655, where PD tests were timing out before GCE PD attach/detach calls could complete. We're working with the GCE team to improve performance and reduce latency.

If the pod never gets out of pending state, then you might've hit a bug. In that case, grab your kubelet log and open an issue at https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/

Answer (score 1):

At least from my feeling, using PersistentVolumeClaims are working much faster. You can nearly instantly destroy and recreate replication controllers.

See: http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/user-guide/persistent-volumes/README.html

Comment: Thanks! This improves the issue  but there is still a delay of 20-60 seconds till a pod reaches the `Running` state. See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34854472/454103