# Google Compute Engine: "Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.4-2) ..." it takes a long time every time i update or upgrade

Tags: debian, google-compute-engine

Every time I do an update or upgrade it takes a long time (several minutes) showing the following:

```
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.4-2) ...
```

After that long wait, everything ends correctly.

Is there a way to get around this without putting the system at risk?

In [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/272248), several solutions are suggested:

**Solution 1:**

```
sudo apt-get remove -y --purge man-db
```

**Solution 2:**

```
sudo mandb -t
rm -rf /var/cache/man
sudo mandb -c
```

**Solution 3:**

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Is there a specific solution for Google Compute Engine?

Answer (score 6):

You could remove `man-db` (why on the Earth server needs man pages?):

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge man-db
```

or tell not to rebuild cache via debconf:

```
echo "set man-db/auto-update false" | sudo debconf-communicate && sudo dpkg-reconfigure man-db
```

Also you could disable the cache rebuilding in hackish way by removing "magic" file:

```
sudo rm -f /var/lib/man-db/auto-update
```

Answer (score 0):

Try resizing your boot disk. In short, smaller disks have worse performance. Increasing the size of the book disk will improve the read and write speed.

Related to:

[Google Compute Engine VM disk is very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23683271/google-compute-engine-vm-disk-is-very-slow)